# jQuery less than function with add and remove classes

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add and remove classes before and after the width set, Once width is less than 1140 the addclass and remove classes work perfectly but when the with is more than 1140 remove class and add class dosnt work. If I could get any help I'd really and truly aprecaite it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    var low = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var pageWidth = $(window).width();
    if (pageWidth <= 1140) {
        low = true;
        $('.studio .thirtyheight').removeClass('thirtyheight').addClass('workfullheight');
        $('.studio .sixtyheight').removeClass('sixtyheight').addClass('workfullheighttwo');
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 1140) {
            if (!low) {
                low = true;
                $('.studio .thirtyheight').removeClass('thirtyheight').addClass('workfullheight');
                $('.studio .sixtyheight').removeClass('sixtyheight').addClass('workfullheighttwo');
            }
        }
        else if (low) {
            low = false;
             $('.studio .workfullheight').addClass('thirtyheight').removeClass('workfullheight');
             $('.studio .workfullheighttwo').addClass('sixtyheight').removeClass('workfullheighttwo');
        }
    });
});




});
```

Comment: try to change it to `$html.addClass('thirtyheight').removeClass('workfullheight')`. And why are you returning it / separating it with `,`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


var low = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pageWidth = $(window).width();
    if (pageWidth <= 1140) {
        low = true;
        $('.studio .thirtyheight').removeClass('thirtyheight').addClass('workfullheight');
        $('.studio .sixtyheight').removeClass('sixtyheight').addClass('workfullheighttwo');
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 1140) {
            if (!low) {
                low = true;
                $('.studio .thirtyheight').removeClass('thirtyheight').addClass('workfullheight');
                $('.studio .sixtyheight').removeClass('sixtyheight').addClass('workfullheighttwo');
            }
        }
        else if (low) {
            low = false;
             $('.studio .workfullheight').addClass('thirtyheight').removeClass('workfullheight');
             $('.studio .workfullheighttwo').addClass('sixtyheight').removeClass('workfullheighttwo');
        }
    });
});




});
```

Answer (score 1):

you forget else case

use it then it will work

```
var $window = $(window),
      $html = $('.studio .thirtyheight'),
      $htmltwo = $('.studio .sixtyheight');
        if ($window.width() < 1140) {
          return $html.addClass('workfullheight').removeClass('thirtyheight'),      
          $htmltwo.addClass('workfullheighttwo').removeClass('sixtyheight');
        }else{
          $html.removeClass('workfullheight').addClass('thirtyheight'), 
          $htmltwo.removeClass('workfullheighttwo').addClass('sixtyheight');
}
```

Comment: When resizing window even with resize code the classed still ain't been removed any suggestions ?

Comment: apply  resize (http://api.jquery.com/resize/) when resize event occur then call your code itys works

Comment: I've had a look through and this still isn't working to plan, I've updated my example above. Let me know if you see anything out the ordanary.